# How many folder a windows operating system can support?

Tags: windows-7

I have following usage scenario. I perform some tests and store its result as txt file in my windows 7 PC. The result is stored sequentially starting from 1.

```
C:\Tests\1\Data.txt
C:\Tests\2\Data.txt
C:\Tests\3\Data.txt
C:\Tests\4\Data.txt
C:\Tests\n\Data.txt
```

I want to know whether there is total folder limit can be created in windows 7 ultimate?

Comment: Ahh, I remember MSDOS had the old limit. . .

Comment: These limits are derived far more from the filesystem format than from the operating system.  It makes more sense to ask about the limits of FAT, NTFS, and so forth than the limits of MS-DOS and Windows NT.

Answer (score 3):

NTFS can hold a maximum of 4,294,967,295 objects in a directory. But you're likely to kill the drive looking for all of them long before you reach that.

Comment: To be clear, "objects" are both files and folders.